# Add multiline string after specific string

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, string

I´m trying to insert a multi-line string in a file after a specific string was found. I already searched and tried a lot of options, but none of them returned the result I expected.

Here is the block I want to edit:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var log = require("cf-nodejs-logging-support");

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express(); //After this line I want to insert several lines

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

And an example of the lines I'd like to insert:

```
function x (test){
    console.log("TEST");
}
```

So the final file should then look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var log = require("cf-nodejs-logging-support");

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

function x (test){
    console.log("TEST");
}

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

One of the potential solutions I tried is the following code block, but I couldn't get it to insert multiple lines that included spaces:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ren in.txt in.tmp
set p=
for /f %%a in (in.tmp) do (
if "%%a"=="5" if "!p!"=="var app = express();" Echo 4 >> in.txt
Echo %%a >>in.txt
set p=%%a
)
del in.tmp
```

I would highly prefer a solution that does not require any additional software to be installed. But if there is no other way this would also be OK. I´m currently working on a Windows 7 PC, but this script should also work on Windows 10.

My entire script (which is much bigger then what I showed here) is written as simple batch file.

Comment: just to clarify (based on the block you tried) - you want to insert the block after the `var app = express();` string and not after the actual line it's on, correct?

Comment: This is correct. The multi-line string should be  inserted after `var app = express();` and the final result should look like the example i´ve provided.

Comment: 1st without `"delims="` your code will only get the first space/tab separated word from each line. 2nd for /f will skip empty lines if not taking precautions. 3rd if you want to insert ***after*** a specific line first print that line. To insert multiple lines use a (code block) following the condition. For that condition I'd use findstr to check with a bit more flexibility using Regular Expressions (as limited they are with findstr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through a lot of overly-complex methods before coming up with the following:

```
@echo off

set "txt=C:\Your\Text\File.txt"
set "old=var app = express();"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%txt%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%txt%" ') do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    if not "!line!" == "!old!" >>"%txt%" echo(!line!
    if "!line!" == "!old!" (
        echo(!old!
        echo.
        echo(function x ^(test^)^{
        echo(   console.log^("TEST"^);
        echo(^}
    )>>"%txt%"
)

endlocal
```

It's actually really straight forward - the only fancy part here is the `'type "%txt%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%txt%" '` bit because it prevents us from having to create a new file, and it also requires us to remove the line counting stuff from the beginning of the `!line!` variable before writing it back to our file (this is what the `set "line=!line:*]=!"` does).

Beyond that, this just looks through all of your lines and if they aren't `var app = express();` it just echo's the line as-is back into the file; if the line *is* `var app = express();` it instead echo's `var app = express();` followed by a blank line (`echo.`) and then the lines you were looking to add. The other thing to keep in mind was to escape the `(`'s, `)`'s, and `}`'s.

There may be an issue if you have `]`'s elsewhere in the script, so if you have any questions just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But if I execute your script it says "The System cannot find the given path" (German to English translation). I have the script and the text file with the code block that should be changed in a separate folder. The name of the text file is `in.txt`. Do you have any idea what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: That's totally my fault - in copying and pasting my test script over I left out the line that sets the `txt` variable. I've edited my answer - you can edit the variable line so that it's `set "txt=C:\Full\Location\Of\in.txt"` - this way you won't have to add your full `in.txt` path in all those places throughout the script. Let me know if that helps or if you have any questions!

Comment: Ah thank you so much!!! It works perfectly now :)

Comment: It was no problem - I had seen a lot a different ways to go about that problem but never had an opportunity to dig in and develop something I liked; happy to help!